# SVN "warning" E235000 makes things uncommitable

Tags: android, svn

I am using SVN Subversion in my Android project.

I checked out the project, made a lot of changes, tried to commit. I have this message on the "Commit Changes" screen:

```
Warning: not all local changes may be shown due to an error: svn: E235000: In file '/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/subversion/subversion-67/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c' line 9534: assertion failed (child_presence != svn_wc__db_status_not_present)
```

But I can hit commit. Unfortunately it fails with the same error.

I tried to clean the svn, with the result that if I try to commit the single file it gives me:

```
Error: Wrong committed revision number: -1
```

Any idea on how I cane resolve this issue?

Comment: This seems to be a crash of svn.exe. What Subversion version is installed on your computer?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. version is 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existed project and checkout again. I resolved my similar issue: error updating changes: svn: E235000: In file '/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/subversion/subversion-71/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c' line 4122: assertion failed

Answer (score 0):

For these types of errors, we can resolve the conflicts from the current SVN path for all the files and directories and then do the following commands.

```
svn cleanup 
svn up
```

If the above command works fine then the issue is resolved.